# ListView Items list is empty but SelectedItems still has elements in it (c#/wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListView which is bound to a CollectionViewSource (the source of which is an ObservableCollection. `myList` in example below).

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding myList}" IsLiveGroupingRequested=true />

<ListView Name="itemsList"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  Margin="0,0,5,0"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
                  SelectionChanged="itemsList_SelectionChanged"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"                      
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

I select one item in the list.

The problem that I am having is that when I clear the `ItemsSource` collection.
If I do `myList.Clear()` the `itemsList.Items` collection is empty as expected but the `itemsList.SelectedItems` still has the selected element in it. I deselected the item using it's `IsSelected` Property and that didn't work.
Even after I do `itemsList.SelectedItems.Clear()/RemoveAt(0)/UnselectAll()` it still has that one selected item in it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried itemsList.SelectedItem=null ?

Comment: Can you provide a full working example, so we can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the `.Source` collection of the `CollectionViewSource` **fails to emit a `CollectionChanged` event** when it is cleared. For example, when the source is a simple `ArrayList` (that doesn't notify of changes), then the behavior will be just as you described.

Without a corresponding event being emitted, the `ListView` doesn't know it should update its internal item cache and selected items list.

(The `.Items` property, on the other hand, seems to actually check the source each time it is called, so it will report a `.Count` of `0` if the source has been cleared.)

In order to propagate the `myList.Clear()` change to the `CollectionViewSource` and `ListView`, make sure that `myList` is actually something that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and correctly emits `CollectionChanged` whenever it is cleared.

Comment: Thank you for that. `myList` is an ObservableCollection so it would be implementing the `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Also what I do not understand is that why calling listview.SelectedItems.Clear() explicitly does not clear the list.

Comment: @ababeel Would be nice of you to accept the right answer. If you want to clear the list you should notify the ListView of the recent changes, one way or another. ...SelectedItems.Clear() doesn't notify it. You still should call RaisePropertyChanged("yourList") after clearing it

Comment: @ababee: Strange, if I hook up your XAML snippet to a `myList` of type `ObservableCollection`, the ListView responds just fine to `myList.Clear()`. Maybe there's a bug in a part of your code that you haven't shown. Can you create a minimal self-contained program that exhibits the issue?

Comment: @smls thank you, yes I am working on the example that exhibits the problem.